# Categorizing words in predetermined groups with the use of R

Tags: r, nlp, grouping

I am currently working on a project where I have stumbled upon an issue.

I have a column containing short strings of text e.g.:

- a news conference
- a radio show
- a TV ad
- a speech in Phoenix

It would be very beneficial if I could short these sentences down to categories. Since I have a lot of observations, I hope R can do it for me.

To give an example, I would like for the above examples to be categorized as:

- conference
- radio
- ad
- speech

How would you approach this? There would in total be about 20 predetermined categories, in which the strings should be added only if the string contains a word similar to the category name.

I hope that I have provided you with enough information for you to help me :-)

Best regards,
Lasse

Answer (score 0):

Using the library `stringr`:

```
v <- c("a news conference",
       "a radio show",
       "a TV ad",
       "a speech in Phoenix")

categories <- c("conference",
                "radio",
                "ad",
                "speech")

library(stringr)
str_extract(v, paste0(categories, collapse = "|"))
[1] "conference" "radio"      "ad"         "speech"
```

You can made this more flexible too by using `stringr::regex` to ignore case: `regex(paste0(...), ignore_case = T)`